# Shift operation implementation in java

Tags: java, c, language-implementation

I recently used the shift operators in Java and noticed that the `>>` operator does not have the same meaning as `>>` in C. In Java `>>` is Signed shift that keeps the first bit at the same value. In Java the equivalent to C shift is the `>>>` operator. The left shift operator (`<<`) is the same as in C and just shifts ignoring the first bit.

The things I wondered are

- Why make this change?
- Why is the notation not consistent so >> and << are signed shift and >>> and <<< are unsigned?
- Is there any use for a signed shift operator?

Comment: It's necessary because Java has no unsigned types. Btw it is already as you suggest: >> is signed and >>> is unsigned. There is no <<< because it would do the same thing as << anyway.

Comment: AFAIK `a >> b` is a signed shift in C for signed types too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23

Comment: No in C all the shift opperations are machine dependent but most of the time >> is unsigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never any need for a sign-aware left shift, since 2:s complement representation stores the sign in the most significant bit.

There's no difference between a value shifted one bit to the left in some kind of "sign-aware" manner, there's nothing you can do differently. Shift the bits to the left, insert a 0 in the least significant bit, and you're done.

With signed numbers, shifting right is *not* so clear-cut, which is why there are two operators.

Comment: But any kind of shifting will change the most significant bit. Left shifting 0111 (7) using signed ints will result in 1110 (-2)

Comment: That's correct.  _Any_ kind of shifting will do that.  So it doesn't matter which kind you use.

Comment: Well, yes, what do you propose the result of such a shift should be? You can't represent 14 (= 7 << 1) with a 4 bit signed integer, so whatever result you get is going to be garbage anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the meaning of `>>` and `>>>` has always been the same in Java.

> Why make this change?

Machine independence. The meaning of `>>` is somewhat implementation dependent in C.

Comment: +1 Java was created to abstract from the underlying hardware, so each operator work the same way on every computer.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, exactly. The JVM (Java Virtual Machine) is that abstract hardware that allows Java to "Write once, run everywhere" (or so they marketed :-).

Answer (score 1):

Signed left shift and unsigned left shift are exactly equivalent, so there's no need to have a separate operator.

On the other hand, Java has no unsigned types, so it can't depend on the type to figure out what shift to use.

For reference, I think you have it backwards -- `>>` is signed right shift, `>>>` is unsigned right shift.